# Unknown key name 'ExecRestart' in section 'Service'

Tags: linux, systemd

I have this systemd unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/ei-integrator.service` as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Integrator
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/tmp/ei-6.6.0/bin/integrator.sh start
ExecStop=/tmp/ei-6.6.0/bin/integrator.sh stop
ExecRestart=/tmp/ei-6.6.0/bin/integrator.sh restart
PIDFile=/tmp/ei-6.6.0/pid.pid
User=wso2user
Group=wso2
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And when I try to `systemctl start ei-integrator.service` it gives me the following error:

> /etc/systemd/system/ei-integrator.service:8: Unknown key name 'ExecRestart' in section 'Service', ignoring.

Can someone help me?

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is "ExecReload". Try using "ExecReload" instead of "ExecRestart" and see if it works.

You can find the available Exec commands in the following documentation.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

More discussions are available here:
https://github.com/wso2/puppet-ei/issues/70
https://systemd-devel.freedesktop.narkive.com/Ln2Sc9Ot/execrestart